# How to do regex match in a string with quotes in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Given the string:

```
/home   "1020....2010" main
```

I would like `home`, `1020` and `2010` using regex, but keep having problems with the quote. Can anyone help me out?

---

Thank you guys for your post. I realize that my code might have some problem. Here it is

string pattern[1] = @"blablabla";
string pattern[2] = @"blablabla";
......

foreach (string s in pattern) {
     if (regex.match(line, s).success) {
            ......
      }
}

Then there is error saying unexpected character "\"

Comment: What kind of problem with the quote? You can't get it to match without capturing the quotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the pattern:

```
/(\w+)\s+"(\d+)\.+(\d+)"
```

And `home` (or any other name after the `/`) will be in `$1`, the first number in `$2` and the last number in `$3`.

**EDIT 1**

I thought the `@` should work, but couldn't get it to compile in ideone.com. This does work however:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class RegexTest 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Regex r = new Regex("/(\\w+)\\s+\"(\\d+)\\.+(\\d+)\""); 
        Match m = r.Match("/home   \"1020....2010\" main ");
        Console.WriteLine("$1 = " + m.Groups[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("$2 = " + m.Groups[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("$3 = " + m.Groups[3]);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
$1 = home
$2 = 1020
$3 = 2010
```

Test rig: http://ideone.com/TpQwf

**EDIT 2**

As @Seattle mentioned in the comments, when using the convenient `@` before a regex-string, the double quotes needs to be escaped by placing a double quote in front of it (not a backslash!):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"/(\w+)\s+""(\d+)\.+(\d+)""");
```

Comment: Thanks, but it keeps telling me the error  "Unexpected character "\""

Comment: the `@` symbol requires that the quotes be escaped differently. `@"/(\w+)\s+""(\d+)\.+(\d+)"""`

Answer (score 0):

For the above, you want something like:

```
/(\w+) "(\d+)\.+(\d+)" (\w+)
```

Also check this:

- [Regex to match all except a string in quotes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614410/regex-to-match-all-except-a-string-in-quotes-in-c)

Comment: Why create a character class from the quote? And wouldn't you want to group the `\w+` and `\d+` matches?

Comment: You're welcome of course! Note that in the example of the OP, there's more than one space after `home`. If you fix that, you will have copied my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a quote character (or other special characters), you can escape it using a backslash. So `\"` in your regex will match a " character.